# DHCP leases flash of Docker

Tags: dhcp, docker

I've docker container, it uses internal DHCP to assign the IP to its Network Interface.

Each time I stop and run the container again, the new IP is assigned, ex: 172.17.0.2, 172.17.0.3, 172.17.0.4 etc

Once I restart computer, the DHCP starts to assign IP from the beginning - 172.17.0.2

Is there any way to flash the current DHCP cache (leases) to always have 172.17.0.2 IP assigned when I run a container again without restarting PC?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the easiest way to release the docker's DHCP cache by just restarting docker ex:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

It is not the same as only DHCP release, but it does what I need.